# SSMS saves in a different encoding when saving a modified stored procedure instead of a new file

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

I have a problem while saving a stored procedure in SSMS, without specifying encoding: default encoding is UTF16-LE BOM instead of `SQLFile.sql` that uses UTF8...

I need it to be UTF-8 for git compliance aspects.

Context :

- Windows 10
- SQL Server Management Studio v19.1.56.0
- Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU23) (KB5030333) - 15.0.4335.1 (X64)
  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Steps to reproduce:

- Open an existing stored procedure from Object Browser on a SQL Server instance
- Save as without changing the encoding.
  It's saved as UTF16-LE BOM (notepad++ / little-endian). This kind of encoding doesn't work well with Git since it reads it as binary
- Create a new SQL file, then save it.
  It's saved as UTF-8 because `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql\SQLFile.sql` "uses" UTF-8 encoding - this is the default encoding for new files.

What I've tried :

- Changing `SQLFile.sql` encoding but it's already UTF-8
- Changing option in SSMS menus - none found.

Of course, I have a workaround as I can save the file with specific encoding, but the team wants it to be automatic so we don't have to think for every procedure...

Thanks

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Both a new query and the query when going to Create To generated a UTF-8 file.

Comment: If you want to be scripting out your objects for Source Control, however, why are you not using a database project? There's multiple options out there to do so, including SSDT (in Visual Studio), Database Projects (in ADS), Redgate SQL Source Control...

Comment: @ThomA to be more explicit about "Open an existing stored procedure from Object Browser on a SQL Server instance", you have to right click on a procedure in the objects navigator and choose "Modify" -> this will open a new child window with complete procedure code. Then save it as described after.

Comment: Seems like I, inadvertently, found the solution for you then; use CREATE To/CREATE or ALTER to instead.

Comment: @ThomA This is a workaround I've also found ; I just want a solution for "all" the ways developers use to "modify" a procedure. I prefer a generic solution through ssms or SQL Server parameter instead of basic workaround... Thanks anyway !

Comment: Then, like I said, why aren't you using a project, isntead of ad-hoc scripting out?

Comment: ok, but I cannot force every developer to "not" get procedure with the bad method. So if one uses it, I'd like to have a sustainable solution to get through...

Comment: ... *"why aren't you using a project, instead of ad-hoc scripting out?"* You're yet to answer that question.

Comment: Because using a project does not ensure that someone use "modify procedure" :-)

Comment: No, because they are in the project, and that project is in UTF-8, and that project is also in source control, which is the root of the question.

Comment: The project method uses local hard drived files so ok but it's still a workaround.
If someone use the "modify procedure" option and saves the file in the project, I'm not sure it will save it as UTF8
Have to test that !

Comment: If someone uses modify procedure then they aren't modifying the project... Change your process. Clearly, you want these procedures in source control, so use a project in source control. Then your developers work in the project, commit changes in the project to git, and deploy, from the project, to the server(s). Yes, everyone has the files locally, but that are all *commited* to your source control repo, so that *everyone* is working  from the branhces, where they can push and pull changes.